# How to get raw response stream using aiohttp?

Tags: python, aiohttp

I need to get raw (compressed) content. My goal is to save it to S3 as it is. It is easy to do with `requests`:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://google.com', stream=True)
content = response.raw.read()  # b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00...'
```

However with `aiohttp` I always get already ungzipped content:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def download(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            content = await response.content.read()  # b'<!doctype html><html...' 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(download('http://google.com'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class aiohttp.ClientSession(
    *,
    connector=None,
    loop=None,
    cookies=None,
    headers=None,
    skip_auto_headers=None,
    auth=None,
    json_serialize=json.dumps,
    version=aiohttp.HttpVersion11,
    cookie_jar=None,
    read_timeout=None,
    conn_timeout=None,
    timeout=sentinel,
    raise_for_status=False,
    connector_owner=True,
    auto_decompress=True,
    proxies=None
)
```

Try to set auto_decompress=false
[docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientSession)

Comment: I can't believe that I missed it.

Comment: @Raz :) it happens, no big deal, i'we burned myself many times when being lazy to read docs.